# create new dataframes from a master database in R

Tags: r, loops

I have a database of different notifiable diseases.

I want to extract a dataframe for each disease in that database so that I can make an automated report form a template in Rmarkdown.

I created a function for creating the dataframe

NMC <- is master database

The database lists all conditions reported

I created a list of those conditions

```
conditions <- list(unique(NMC$Condition))
```

I then created a function to create a new dataframe based on the condition

```
newdf <- function(data, var){
  var <- data %>% filter(data$Condition %in% paste0(var))
  var
}
```

Now I want to run my function to create a number of new dataframes from the master database. I thought of doing a for loop:

```
for (df in conditions){
  df <- newdf(NMC, "df")
}
```

Which runs but doesn't give me anything.

So I found split(), but this hasn't perfectly solved my problem as I still need to type out all the conditions to get each df to apply to the r template.

```
NMC <- split(NMC, factor(NMC$Condition), drop= FALSE)

#then to get a specifc df (which is laborious)

rubella <- NMC$congenitalrubellasyndrome

# How can i get the dataframes per condition into my environemnt, or access them easily, maybe with %>% fucntion?
```

My end goal is to then apply an R template to each data frame so that i have a standard epicurve/descriptive stats for each disease.

Thanks

Comment: Are you sure you need separate data frames? With the `split()` function that you already discovered, you get a list of data frames. You might use `lapply()` or similar functions to process each data frame. Or, you might try applying one of the many different approaches for grouped operations to your original data frame. If you want to stick with the original approach, see the `assign()` function. It can do what you want.

Answer (score 0):

```
> df <- data.frame(a = rep(letters[1:10], each = 3), x = 1:30)

> for (i in df$a) {
+   assign(i, df[df$a == i, ])
+ }

> ls()
 [1] "a"  "b"  "c"  "d"  "df" "e"  "f"  "g"  "h"  "i"  "j"

> a
  a x
1 a 1
2 a 2
3 a 3
```

But see my comment above.